# How to background a play webserver so that terminating an SSH session does not kill it?

Tags: azure, ssh, playframework, playframework-2.0, webserver

Excuse the noob question but I am having some trouble with a Play Webserver. Currently I start up the app using 'activator run', which as I understand is the dev method of starting this up.

The actual webserver is located on a remote azure cloud VM so I have no gui access and therefore can't leave the activator web interface running to keep the process alive.

The trouble I have is that when my SSH session dies so does the webserver.

I have tried '&' to background the process, and also nohup with no success. In either of those cases the webserver does not even start.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `activator start` is production mode, which will allow you to detach the process. There must be a duplicate of this somewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Ctrl+D` to exit the play console while keeping the web server process running.

Source: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Production